# What is the pom filename format in remote repositories?

Tags: maven

Sometimes I see with name $BASE_REPO/groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.pom and few others with simple $BASE_REPO/groupId/artifactId/version/pom.xml
What is the right format? Is it client maven version dependent?

Comment: maven deploys the artifacts with its pom to local repo as your first exmaple, $BASE_REPO/groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.pom

Comment: Thanks for the response.I was also expecting the same. But, the libvirt maven repo doesnt have it (http://libvirt.org/maven2/org/libvirt/libvirt/0.5.1/ ) and my maven(Apache Maven 3.2.3) doesnt complain when I use it whereas a friend of mine's does(Apache Maven 3.0.5)  (http://markmail.org/thread/z3wratdglnl66fvx)